# Swift Decodable, Endpoint returns completely different types

Tags: swift, codable, decodable, swift-extensions, jsondecoder

With API I'm working with, I have a case where 1 API Endpoint can return completely different responses, based on if the call was successful or not.
In case of **success**, API Endpoint returns an Array of requested objects, in the root, something like this:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    ...
]
```

which I'm normally decoding with `try JSONDecoder().decode([Object].self, from: data)`

In case of an **error**, API Endpoint returns something completely different, looks like this:

```
{
    "error": "value1",
    "message": "value2",
    "status": "value3"
}
```

and decoding with `try JSONDecoder().decode([Object].self, from: data)` normally fails.

Now, **my question is**, is there a way, to decode error response keys, in this kind of (I would say not so normally architectured API), **WITHOUT** creating a -what I call- *plural* object named `Objects` that would have optional properties `error`, `message`, `status`, and for example `objects`.
My thinking got somewhere to extending Array `where Element == Object` and somehow trying to decode `error`, `message`, `status`, but I'm hitting `Conformance of 'Array<Element>' to protocol 'Decodable' was already stated in the type's module 'Swift'`. Maybe it's not even possible to do it that way, so any other, even completely different, suggestion would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to decode the root object of the JSON as enum with associated values

```
struct Item : Decodable {
    let key1, key2, key3 : String
}

struct ResponseError  : Decodable {
    let error, message, status : String
}

enum Response : Decodable {
    case success([Item]), failure(ResponseError)
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = .success(try container.decode([Item].self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            self = .failure(try container.decode(ResponseError.self))
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    switch result {
        case .success(let items): print(items)
        case .failure(let error): print(error.message)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

It's good practice to catch only the specific `.typeMismatch` error and hand over other errors instantly to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to decode [Object] and if that fails, decode another struct with your error keys.

Comment: thanks for your response, but it wouldn't work in some cases. For example, with Generics, when the whole set of Networking Classes (like APIRouter) is expecting to receive a type of an object that should be decoded. Like `let objectsAPI = APIRouter<[Object]>()`

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an "abstract" struct that is the receiver of the decode call and let that struct decode the correct type and return a `Result` object

```
enum ApiErrorEnum: Error {
    case error(ApiError)
}

struct ResponseHandler: Decodable {
    let result: Result<[ApiResult], ApiErrorEnum>

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        do {
            let values = try container.decode([ApiResult].self)
            result = .success(values)
        } catch {
            let apiError = try container.decode(ApiError.self)
            result = .failure(.error(apiError))
        }
    }
}
```

and it could then be used for instance using a closure

```
func decodeApi(_ data: Data, completion: @escaping (Result<[ApiResult], ApiErrorEnum>?, Error?) -> ()) {
    do {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseHandler.self, from: data)
        completion(decoded.result, nil)
    } catch {
        completion(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `Result` is the right way to go. I'd recommend you get rid of the first variant completely, or at least change it into an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Utilise a do-catch block to allow you try decoding one type, and if that fails try the other option.  I quite like to use an enum to handle the result...

```
struct Opt1: Codable {
   let key1, key2, key3: String
}

struct Opt2: Codable {
   let error, message, status: String
}

enum Output {
   case success([Opt1])
   case failure(Opt2)
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
var output: Output

do {
   let opt1Array = try decoder.decode([Opt1].self, from: data)
   output = .success(opt1Array)
} catch {
   let opt2 = try decoder.decode(Opt2.self, from: data)
   output = .failure(opt2)
}
```