# How to handle failure cases of JSON response using Codable?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have some JSON response, that I take from a server. In success case, it might be like:

```
{
  "success": true, 
  "data": [
    {
       /// something here 
    }
  ]
}
```

If all server responses would be successful, it would be really easy to parse that JSON. But we have also failure cases like:

```
{
  "success": false, 
  "msg": "Your session expired",
  "end_session": true 
}
```

That means we need to handle two cases. As you noticed, attributes like `success, msg` may occur in any response. In order to handle that, I created following struct:

```
struct RegularResponse<T: Codable>: Codable {
let success: Bool
let msg: String?
let endSession: Bool?
let data: T?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case success, msg, data
    case endSession = "end_session"
}

}
```

It may contain some data if response is successfull or otherwise, it is possible to identify why the error occurred(using `success` attribute or `msg`). Parsing process would go like following:

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(RegularResponse<MyModel>.self, from: data)

            if model.success {
                // do something with data 
            } else {
               // handle error 
            }
```

Everything works fine, but what if following JSON comes as following:

```
{
  "success": true, 
  "name": "Jon Snow", 
  "living_place": "Nights Watch",
  //some other fields
}
```

Here, I don't have `data` attribute. It means, my `RegularResponse` cannot be parsed. So, the question is how to handle these kind of situations? My idea for solution is simple: always put data in success cases into `data` field on my API. By doing so, my `RegularResponse` will always work, no matter what is inside `data`. But, it requires changes on a server side. Can this be fixed in a client side, not changing a server side? In other words, how to handle above situation in Swift using Codable?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792946/9223839) for a way to solve this with a custom init

Comment: You should definitely make an agreement with the backend for a standard response as you already mentioned by sending any object inside `data`. Otherwise you have to create many `ResponseResult/DataTypes` to parse various response with some other annoying handling.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but if you know that your error response is in that shape, i.e.:

```
{
  "success": false, 
  "msg": "Some error", 
  "end_session": "true",
}
```

then you could make another Codable struct/class that follows this response.

```
struct ErrorResponse: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let msg: String
    let end_session: String
}
```

and then when you are responding to your JSON you could adjust your code to:

```
if let successResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(RegularResponse<MyModel>.self, from: data) {
    //handle success
} else if let responseError = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from data) {
    //handle your error
}
```

Comment: It's better to keep using `cameCase` in `Swift` structures and `.convertFromSnakeCase` `.convertFromSnakeCase` for your `JSONDecoder`. It will handle `snake_case` -> `camelCase` internally.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that it hides any other errors related to the decoding if they occurs.

Comment: @user28434 I agree I just followed the JSON response that the OP posted, you could use CodingKeys to deal with this too.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's fair but it can be adjusted with a try catch, where you then try to decode the error response in the catch block.

Comment: if `msg, end_session, success` moves to `ErrorResponse`, then what `RegularResponse<T>` will look like?

Comment: @neo they don't move, you just end up with two structs to handle the different responses you have. Your `RegularResponse<T>` remains, and can handle the success cases, and your `ErrorResponse` handles the cases where you're receiving the error properties.

Comment: Does the success property get used after the alterations?