# Server Response Not matching model (no records) in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

sorry if the question is vague but I am trying to be as expressive as possible.

I have the following model:

```
struct Posts: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let content: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case title
        case content
    }
}
```

the server response if a post is found would be the same model no issues because the JSON matches the model .

but if the server returns an error post not found, this would be the response JSON:

```
{
"error": "No records found"
}
```

I receive the following when this happens:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil) ("id").", underlyingError: nil))

what would be the best approach to handle this issue?

UPDATE:

Thank you jnpdx!

So, I did a ErrorResponse Struct, and it did catch the error response like so:

```
struct ErrorResponse: Codable {
    let error: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case error
    }
}
```

So in my APIServices file, how do I handle this?

```
// this is what gets the Post data

let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Post?.self, from: data)

//Do I need another JSONDecoder to also catch the error below the above line like this?

let decodedDataError = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse?.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Make a struct to represent the error response (`MyError` or something like that). Try to decode as `Post.self` first. If that fails, try to decode as `MyError.self`. If that fails, you have a different, unknown situation.

Comment: Thank you jnpdx!

So, I did a ErrorResponse Struct, and it did catch the error response like so:

```

struct ErrorResponse: Codable {
    let error: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case error
    }
}

```

So in my APIServices file, how do I handle this?

```
// this is what gets the Post data

let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Post?.self, from: data)
Do I need another JSONDecoder to also catch the error below the above line like this?

let decodedDataError = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse?.self, from: data)

```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792754/swift-decodable-endpoint-returns-completely-different-types/58797907#58797907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, we discussed creating a struct to model the error, which it looks like you've done. To address your followup, no, you don't need a separate `JSONDecoder`. You also probably should not be decoding optionals.

There's not just a single way to do this correctly, but your function *might* look something like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
  let post = try decoder.decode(Post.self, from: data)
  //handle the post
} catch {
  //try to decode an error
  if let error = try? decoder.decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: data) {
    //handle an API error
  }
  //handle an unknown error
}
```